# bug change recurring google calendar event visibility from private back to default

Tags: google-calendar-api

If I have a google calendar event with a resource invited, set its visibility to private for all events, save, and then set it back to "default".  It results in the resource not reverting back to default.  Furthermore, if I try to change the event in the resource's calendar to default, the change again is not propagated.

Another weird thing I've noticed is that if you then remove the resource, and re-add it, it comes back with the same visibility + status.

Same thing happens in the UI.

Seems like a bug on the back-end.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried asking for the [Calendar API support](https://developers.google.com/calendar/support) about the bug that you are encountering?

Comment: I was told I should post the question here, I'll try opening an issue as well.  Actually I found several more issues.